# How can I add known type to Azure Functions, as there is no app config

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have some knowntype in app config. If i wanna move my code to Azure Function, where can I add those value

```
      <knownType type="ImardaAtomGatewayBusiness.AccelerationPart, ImardaAtomGatewayBusinessInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <knownType type="ImardaAtomGatewayBusiness.AckPart, ImardaAtomGatewayBusinessInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <knownType type="ImardaAtomGatewayBusiness.AnalogInputPart, ImardaAtomGatewayBusinessInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" /
```

Comment: this might help, guide to referencing assemblies in azure functions https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/13/how-to-add-assembly-references-to-an-azure-function-app/

Comment: I know how to assembly the reference, but how does it work with knowntype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this via a config file, since there's no `app.config` file for Azure Functions that you can control.

So, you would have to do that in code. Some ideas can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771560/how-do-you-configure-wcf-known-types-programmatically).